# Do the Lorentz transformations contradict reality by implying time had no beginning?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, causality

Consider the following two points, or events as they are more commonly called, in SpaceTime:

Event 1: $(x,t) = (0,0)$

Event 2: $(x,t) = (a,0)$

Take t=0 to correspond to the first moment in time.

As you can see they are merely two separate locations, Event 2 could be any point in space.  Since their t coordinates are the same they are simultaneous in the unprimed frame.

For two coordinate systems in standard configuration, the general expression from the Lorentz transformations relating the t' coordinate to the t coordinate with c=1 is:

$t' = \gamma (t - vx)$

So

$t'_0 = \gamma(t_0 - vx_0)$

$t'_0 + ∆t' = \gamma(t_0 + ∆t -v(x_0+∆x) )$

Taking the difference yields

$∆t' = \gamma(∆t - v∆x )$

So for the two events at the start of my question, that are simultaneous in the unprimed frame, we have

$∆t' = \gamma(0- va )$

According to the relativity of simultaneity, what is one moment in time in the unprimed frame, corresponds to two moments in time in the primed frame.

This is all because ∆t' isn't zero, and that is the case because ∆t' is a function of spatial coordinates.

Now suppose there is a particle at location (a,0) whose *instantaneous* speed is greater than zero.
Let its instantaneous speed be the constant $v_0.$
Define $a=v_0 dt >0.$
Therefore $a=dx$, so the space-time manifold is locally Minkowskian there.

Therefore $∆t'= \gamma(-vv_0dt).$
Therefore $∆t' <0$, but amounts of time are strictly non-negative.

Suppose $ ∆ t′<0$ simply means that event 2 occurred before event 1 in the primed frame, and $∆ t′>0 $ means that in the primed frame event 2 occurred after event 1.

That supposition implies there was a moment in time before the beginning of time in contradiction to reality.

**PROOF TIME HAD A BEGINNING**

Let Time be the Domain of Discourse.

Let X denote an arbitrary moment in Time.

Let Z denote an arbitrary current moment in Time.

Thus X is an arbitrary constant, and Z is a specific constant.

Thus we can universally generalize on x but we cannot universally generalize on Z.

Define three mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive sets.

**DEFINITIONS**

Past={x|x before Z}

Present={Z}

Future={x|Z before x}

Define Time to be the set of moments in time, that is

Time = Past union Present union Future

Divide the set of moments in time into two mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive classes,

1. the class of moments in time that have been actualized
2. the class of moments in time that have not been actualized

X has been actualized if and only if x is in the past or the present.

X is potentially actualizable if and only if x is in the future.

X is a protostate if and only if
For any moment in time y: if not(x simultaneous to y) then x before y.

x simultaneous to y if and only if not (x before y) and not (y before x).

Suppose there was no protostate, then For any moment in time x, you can find a moment in time y such that: y before x.

By universal instantiation

You can find a moment in time y such that y before Z.

Therefore you can find a moment in time y such that Z is potentially actualizable.

And this holds for any moment in time that was/is/will be the current moment in time, which is basically all moments in time. That means by Class Generalization

For any current moment in time x, you can find a moment in time y such that: x is potentially actualizable.

That means

For any current moment in time x, you can find a moment in time y such that: x is in the future.

That means

For any current moment in time x: x is in the future.

By Class Instantiation we have, "Z is in the Future."

Therefore Z is in the Present and the Future, which is impossible, since those sets are mutually exclusive.

To put this another way:

All moments in time prior to the current moment in time were already the current moment in time.  Thus they have all been actualized.  Therefore you can't find a moment in time y such that y is in the past or present and wasn't potentially actualizable.  But that means all moments in time in the past or present were in the future once.  Which means all moments in time were in the future once, in contradiction to the fact that some moment in Time must be in the present always.

Therefore there was a protostate, which means there was a beginning of time.

Q.E.D

The tricky part of the proof is that some of the propositions have a truth value that varies in time.  To be specific:

Let Q denote the current moment in time.

The proposition denoted by, "Q is potentially actualizable" has a truth value that varies in time.  It's currently false, but a moment ago it was true.

So what we can say is

You can find a moment in time y such that: the statement, "Q is potentially actualizable" denotes a true proposition.

Now every moment in time was/is/will be the current moment in time.  Thus we can replace the specific constant Q with the more arbitrary constant Z, and get a true proposition.  So that means

You can find a moment in time y such that: the statement, "Z is potentially actualizable" denotes a true proposition.

We can now Class generalize on Z to get

For any current moment in time x,  you can find a moment in time y such that: the statement , "x is potentially actualizable" denotes a true proposition.

This means that

For any current moment in time x, you can find a moment in time y such that: the statement , "x is in the future" denotes a true proposition.

The propositional function , " x is in the future" doesn't depend on y, it's not a function of y.

So although

For any x, there is at least one y such that:  f(x, y)

doesn't generally imply

There is at least one y such that for any x: f(x,y)

In the case where f(x,y)=f(x), it does imply it.

Therefore we have

There is at least one moment in time y such that for any current moment in time x : the statement , "x is in the future" denotes a true proposition.

By the theorems of the first order function calculus this means:

The proposition denoted by,:

"for any current oment in time x : x is in the future", is true somewhere in time.

But it is true nowhere in time, because the following proposition is constantly true:

There is at least one current moment in time y such that: y is in the Present.

This is a consequence of the definition of the Present.

Z is an element of the Present.

Now by Existential Class Generalization

There is at least one current moment in time y such that: y is in the Present.

And Z can't be in the Future.  Hence

There is at least one current moment in time y such that: y isn't in the Future.

The contradiction is now evident.

Note: It also follows by Existential Generalization that

There is at least one moment in time y such that: y is in the Present,

but we didn't want that.

Comment: Check out space time diagrams. In a rest frame, you can represent the axes of a moving frame in the same graph. If time is vertical axis, position is horizontal, the world line of a moving particle is the time axis of the moving frame and has slope $1/v$ in $c=1$ units. It can be shown the x axis has slope v. Whatever time axis you use, what's paralell to the lime axis is at the same position in a given coordinate system, whats parallel to the x axis is simultaneous. So one event in one coordinate system shares a time with infinitely many events in the other frame or its own.

Comment: Not physics. You're choosing your assumptions to get the result you want. But the validity of the Lorentz transformation rests on (many!) experiments verifying it.

Answer (score 4):

> Take t=0 to correspond to the first moment in time.

Recall that the Lorentz transform applies locally, meaning it applies in a small enough region of spacetime such that spacetime curvature is negligible. Such a region does not have a "first moment in time". Such regions are open subsets of a 4D manifold, and by virtue of being open subsets there are no events that are on the boundary.

This open subset issue applies even for the big bang, where additionally you will run into the problem that the curvature becomes arbitrarily large so there is no finite region over which the assumption of negligible curvature is valid.

> PROOF TIME HAD A BEGINNING ...

This proof is a mess. It is filled with illogical leaps (For any current moment in time x: x is in the future), undefined terms (current moment), and unwarranted assumptions (some moment in Time must be in the present always).

In the established theory, the mathematical and logical structure of space and time are clear and well founded. Specifically, spacetime is represented by a 4 dimensional pseudo-Riemannian manifold with a metric given by the Einstein field equations. Since a manifold is a topological space there is a neighborhood defined around each point. The neighborhood forms an open ball around each point, meaning that any direction you examine there will be points surrounding it. So there will always be additional points "earlier" than any point in the manifold. There is no closed boundary, by definition.

However, more importantly than the mathematical definition that precludes your proof is the experimental evidence that establishes relativity. Different sets of mathematical assumptions will lead to different conclusions, so the question is which set of assumptions lead to conclusions that are consistent with what we actually observe. That is clearly relativity:

https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/experiments.html

Answer (score 2):

You've assumed that $a \ne 0$ when $t = 0$, which is also a contradiction to reality (if by "reality" you mean the best physical model we have right now of the beginning of the universe, in which all spatial distances approach 0 as $t$ approaches 0).

Of course other possibilities exist: for example, it may be that there is no "first moment" of time. This is logically possible, unless you accept some metaphysical propositions which are not at all universally held by philosophers, and which in any case are outside of the realm of physics.

ETA: More importantly, the Lorentz transformation is just a mapping between coordinate system. There's no particular reason that $t=0$ must correspond to "the beginning of time" in all frames of reference, even if it does so in one. One may choose an arbitrary origin.

Comment: If a must equal zero at t=0, $\forall a$, then I see a contradiction.  All matter was located at that point, and all space was located there.  Thus matter=space. Proving that time had a beginning falls in the domain of the temporal first order function calculus, I will add the proof.

Comment: Whether time has a beginning or not has been debated since at least Aristotle, and one may find voluminous arguments on both sides in the philosophical literature, even today. All of which says that the question is an empirical one, not a logical one, and it's not going to be settled on the Physics Stackexchange website. Moreover, as I mentioned in the edit to my answer, the numbers we assign to time coordinates are arbitrary, so there's no reason they must be positive in all frames of reference even on the assumption that there is a smallest time.